# Two-dimensional facet query

Tags: solr, solr4, facet, faceted-search

I have a simple query which returns counts for two different facets (e.g. authors and categories) with some limit. For instance:

```
select?q=*&facet.field=authors&facet.field=categories&facet.limit=2
```

As the result two lists with two top values each are returned, e.g.:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
  <lst name="authors">
    <int name="Author1">1200</int>
    <int name="Author2">1100</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="categories">
    <int name="Cat1">500</int>
    <int name="Cat2">400</int>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

I would like to present these facets on a two-dimensional table with the count for each pair:

```
      Author1   Author2
Cat1    x         x
Cat2    x         x
```

How can I get the count for each pair? I tried to use [pivot faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting) with the query like this:

```
select?q=*&facet.pivot=authors,categories&facet.limit=2
```

but the response is not what I expect as it can contain something like in the following example where categories in the pivot for *Author2* are different than for *Author1*. The pivot presents top categories for each author and not top categories for the whole query:

```
<lst name="facet_pivot">
  <arr name="authors,categories">
   <lst>
     <str name="field">authors</str>
     <str name="value">Author1</str>
     <int name="count">1200</int>
     <arr name="pivot">
       <lst>
         <str name="field">categories</str>
         <str name="value">Cat1</str>
         <int name="count">450</int>
       </lst>
       <lst>
         <str name="field">categories</str>
         <str name="value">Cat2</str>
         <int name="count">300</int>
       </lst>
     </arr>
   </lst>
   <lst>
     <str name="field">authors</str>
     <str name="value">Author2</str>
     <int name="count">1100</int>
     <arr name="pivot">
       <lst>
         <str name="field">categories</str>
         <str name="value">Cat3</str>
         <int name="count">300</int>
       </lst>
       <lst>
         <str name="field">categories</str>
         <str name="value">Cat4</str>
         <int name="count">250</int>
       </lst>
     </arr>
   </lst>
  </arr>
</lst>
```

Can the pivot query be somehow parameterized to achieve the desired result of is there any other query that I could use for this particular use case?